# search character by character from postgreSQL database show the list in jsp

Tags: postgresql, jsp-tags

i am creating a stock market application in that i want script name must be specific. so i m creating a database of script name. n actually from JSP when i write "b" all the script name begin with b that all are displayed so that can i select a rite script. so help me to find solution.....

thanks  in advance...

Comment: [here is tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/06/tutorial-create-autocomplete-feature-with-java-jsp-jquery.html) to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-like-mysql.aspx...................
i am not a java proffesional bt thought this link might jst help you if what i understood through your question was exactly true...

Comment: I think OP asking for something like auto-suggestion-box.

Comment: Try Full Text Search.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513501/postgresql-full-text-search-how-to-search-partial-words http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208927/multiple-synonym-dictionary-matches-in-postgresql-full-text-searching http://www.developer.com/article.php/3446891